# Excluding lines starting with certain objects from indentation

Tags: indentation

Is there a way to exlude certain lines from indentation ? For example, I'd like to have every line that starts with a certain object, like the `\Longrightarrow` in the following MWE, to *not* be indented. Is there a way to do this without adding `\noindent` at the start of every such line ?

The command should be robust so as to also permit other identifier of such lines than mathematical symbols: More concretely it should be possible to have the option to also indent lines consisting of a sole LaTeX command (like `\textcyr{\char143}`) lines starting with a `\fbox`.

I'd be grateful for every tip!!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

The indentation is visible in this line, as one can see by type a lot of text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text ...

$\Longrightarrow$ Because I used the arrow at the start, this line should *never* be intended.

Now indentation is active again...

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `Longrightarrow` is tricky as you are already in math mode. But other macros that are not in math mode can be redefined as `\let\OlfFbox\fbox` and
`\def\fbox{\noindent\OlfFbox}.`  Then using `\fbox` will automatically not be indented.  If you are willing to use `\Longrightarrow` instead of `$\Longrightarrow$`, then you can use `\let\OldLongrightarrow\Longrightarrow` and 
`\def\Longrightarrow{\noindent\ensuremath{\OldLongrightarrow}}`.

Comment: Actually this comment was, what I was *really* looking for, since I already have several lines that are to be intendet and don't want to change the command of each line to some new command that I define to not be indented, but rather redefine the command (but the answerer couldn't know that of course, since I wasn't precise about this point).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to avoid starting math mode, or it would be too late for removing the indentation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\niLongrightarrow}{%
  \noindent\ensuremath{\Longrightarrow}%
}

\begin{document}

The indentation is visible in this line, as one can see by type a lot of text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text ...

\niLongrightarrow{} Because I used the arrow at the start, this line should *never* be 
intended.

Now indentation is active again and $a\niLongrightarrow b$...

\end{document}
```

[image]

But using `\noindent` is simpler.

Comment: Is there any drawback to redefining the original as `\let\svLRA\Longrightarrow\def\Longrightarrow{\noindent\ensuremath{\svLRA}}`, in case the OP wanted to not introduce a new macro name?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, there are: the symbol is not used in its mathematical meaning, in this case, but just as a graphic device. I used `\ensuremath` for convenience, but `\ensureNONmath` would be better.