# Removing indentation *after* certain objects have been used

Tags: indentation

Is there any way to *automatically* remove any indentation of text right *after* `\includegraphics` or a `\begin{center}` environment is used ? Consider the following MWE pertaining to the use of `\begin{center}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some text...
\includegraphics{some_graphic.png}
Moar text...

\begin{center}
Some centered text...
\par\end{center}

Moar text...

\end{document}
```

I don't want any of the "moar text" to be automatically indented. Using each time a `\noindent` is not an option.

([This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215815/excluding-lines-starting-with-certain-objects-from-indentation) answered question of mine might be of relevance, since there it is explained how to remove indentation of those lines start *star* with a specific object - in contrast here indentation has to be removed from those lines which are *after* some specific objects.)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \includegraphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `\includegraphics` nor `center` cause indentation so really there is nothing to remove. The indent is added at the start of a paragraph, that is, after a blank line or (equivalently) `\par` that ends a paragraph.

If you do not want to start a paragraph, avoid using `\par`

Neither `Moar` is indented here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some text...
\includegraphics{example-image}
Moar text...
\begin{center}
Some centered text...
\end{center}
Moar text...

\end{document}
```

(Please post example code in a form that runs without error when copied)