# Centering graphics without indenting lines afterwards

Tags: graphics, indentation

Is there a way to nicely place a  graphic on a separate new line and  centering it there, without using a `\begin{center}` environment, which wraps around the graphic ?

I don't want to use that environment, as it produces an indentation in the line after the graphic - see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223085/removing-indentation-after-certain-objects-have-been-used) question of mine for an MWE (attention, graphic is missing as I can't link to a picture on the net, so it won't directly compile).

Alternatively I'd also be happy if someone could provide me with a command that does the same as placing `\noindent`s after each of the `\begin{center}` environments (an no, a placing a million of those isn't the solution :)).

Thanks.

Comment: when making MWE you can use images such as `example-image` which are distributed with texlive so generally available

Comment: It seems that you chose to ignore the accepted answer on that question?

Comment: The `center` environment is not relevant here, the indentation is caused by the paragraph start due to the blank line, you would get the same indentation if you removed the `center` and the image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So sorry for the mess, you're right, this question has already been answered. (And thanks for the tip for making MWEs with images.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\cg}[2][scale=1]{%
\par\noindent\hfill\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\hfill\mbox{}\par\noindent}
%--------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
test 
\cg{example-image}
test
test 
\cg[scale=.5]{example-image}
test
\end{document}
```